# Quick way to dump a Wordpress database without digging through configuration files?

Tags: command-line, mysql, php, wordpress

I've got a load of Wordpress sites to move around and modify this afternoon. Yay.

Like any good developer, I want to back up things before I Hulk-out and break everything. The site's files are mostly version controlled (and those that aren't are backed up). The database is something else. There are many sites installed on this server so a central dump isn't as useful as I'd like. I want a site-specific dump.

One of the most annoying things about doing this manually is picking out the details from `wp-config.php`. I wonder if there's a more easy way to process this file and pass its details onto `mysqldump` in one command.

---

I have submitted an answer while writing the question but it's by no means the only way of doing this. If somebody can suggest a better way of handling this, let me know. Just be aware that PHP will allow all sorts of nonsense. Anything used here should accept varied but valid PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Well while writing the question a few ideas popped into my head. This is the first and it appears to work. Instead of trying to manually parse out the wp-config.php file (which could be in any order), I'm going to pick the lines I actually want and make PHP do all the heavy lifting. Here's what I've got:

```
eval $((echo '<?php'; awk '/^define/' wp-config.php; echo 'print "mysqldump -u".DB_USER." -p".DB_PASSWORD." ".DB_NAME." > database-".DB_NAME."-\$(date +%F).sql\n";') | php)
```

What this is actually doing is making a fake PHP script in the pipe, sending that to PHP and then using the output to execute. Here's what we have before PHP processes it:

```
<?php
define('DB_NAME', 'my_lovely_database');
define('DB_USER', 'oli');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'oli');
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
define('DB_COLLATE', '');
define ('WPLANG', '');
print "mysqldump -u".DB_USER." -p".DB_PASSWORD." ".DB_NAME." > database-".DB_NAME."-\$(date +%F).sql\n";
```

When that runs in `php`, it generates a line like so:

```
mysqldump -uoli -poli my_lovely_database > database-my_lovely_database-2014-05-14.sql
```

And we tell `bash` to run that and it creates a new database backup.

Save this as a function or alias in bash and you'll live a long and happy life.